# How do you escape regex strings in Freemarker

Tags: regex, html-parsing, freemarker

I am using the matches string builtin and need to run a regex pattern

`(Views:).*?(span>)(.*?)(<\/div)`

However, Freemarker freaks out because of the ">" character which is a special character in Freemarker.  Any ideas how to get round this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\l` for `<` and `\g` for `>`.

Taken from [a FreeMarker documentation page](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#topic.escapeSequence) which was second item in a [Google search for "freemarker escape string"](http://www.google.com/search?q=freemarker+escape+string).

Oh and be careful trying to parse HTML with regex - with uncontrolled markup it turns difficult very quickly.